# How to solve red square icon of an eclipse view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a plugin in Eclipse that adds a view to a certain category. My problem is that there instead of having the icon that I've choosen for the view I can see a red square. This is only in Show View->Category_Name. When I open the view, the icon is displayed as it is normal.

This is the view extension part of my plugin.xml:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.views">    
           <view
  category="custom_category"
        class="com.warnings.compilation.views.TabViewer"
        id="com.warnings.compilation.view1"
        icon="icons/warning-icon.png"
        name="Log Plugin">

  </view>
  </extension>
```

My build.properties file looks like this:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               icons/,\
               contexts.xml,\
               lib/commons-io-2.4.jar,\
               lib/google-collections-1.0.jar,\
               config/,\
               lib/commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar,\
               lib/commons-configuration2-2.0-alpha1.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This category id is not matching in category tag and in view tag. Correct it.
Make 1 and 2 same.

```
  <category
    id="com.warnings.compilation"   ------- 1
    name="TD4">
  </category>          
  <view
    category="custom_category"      ------- 2
    class="com.warnings.compilation.views.TabViewer"
    id="com.warnings.compilation.view1"
    icon="icons/warning-icon.png"
    name="Log Plugin">

  </view>
  </extension>
```

Comment: I edited my question, that was a test category created by me, the category where I want to insert my view is created by other plugins and it's id is custom_category, sorry

Comment: run your product on clear workspace and also check the dependent plugin is added to the product. Are you able to see the category in the `
ShowViewDialog` if so icons of any other views included in this category are visible?